# How to subset one column in pandas with condition on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like below..

```
     dish_quant_bought    dish_name
              20              A 
              18              B
              20              A
              18              B
              20              A
              18              B
              10              C
              18              B
              10              C
              18              B
              20              D
              20              D
              20              D
              20              D
```

I want to extract corresponding dish_quant_bought for given dish name.. 
So for dish A it should return only 20, for B is 18 ,C is 10 & for D is 20

I am trying with below code but it doesn't work..

```
df_['dish_quant_bought']['dish_name'] == 'A'
```

Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unclear why you have duplicates but you can use a boolean condition to mask the df and return the col of interest:

```
In [256]:
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df

Out[256]:
    dish_quant_bought dish_name
0                  20         A
1                  18         B
6                  10         C
10                 20         D

In [257]:    
df.loc[df['dish_name']=='A', 'dish_quant_bought']

Out[257]:
0    20
Name: dish_quant_bought, dtype: int64
```

The mask on your original df:

```
In [259]:
df['dish_name']=='A'

Out[259]:
0      True
1     False
2      True
3     False
4      True
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
Name: dish_name, dtype: bool
```

You can get the unique value by calling `unique` after the filtering without calling `drop_duplicates` first:

```
In [297]:
df.loc[df['dish_name']=='A', 'dish_quant_bought'].unique()

Out[297]:
array([20], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: or use `np.unique` after the `df.loc` to have a one liner.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if they have the same quantity value, you could get by using groupby and then mean on the selected column, it will produce the same value

```
df.groupby(["dish_name"])["dish_quant_bought"].mean()
```

then just select whatever name you want

Comment: @Serverin that's better idea to have mean.. thanks alot :)